# Finding a user control from the main parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net

HI I have an aspx page ResourceCategories.aspx where in I have registered two user controls:

My problem is I have to access the user control 2)downloadPopUp in 1)ctlCategories on btn click event.

```
 protected void btnArrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

      {

            //lblMessages.Text = String.Empty;
            try
            {
          var userControl = FindControl("ctlPopUp") as UserControl;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
           {
           }
      }
```

I'm still getting the usercontrol value as null. How it can be accessed? I'm able to access only of I register 2nd user control in first user control but not from the main aspx page.i.e;   Registering   in ResourceCenter.ascx. I dont want to nest user control inside another user control.. is there a way ?

Comment: I think you need to reword your question, the part where you describe what is calling what is very muddled. Also, using `try/catch` to catch all exceptions is generally frowned upon, especially when your catch block is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... do the aspx and c# code you show the same page? If that's the case you don't need to use `FindControl`, you should have a property named ctlCategories and ctlPopUp on the code behind

Comment: No... the code is in ResourceCenter.ascx.cs page. I tried by accessing the ctlpopup using the class something like                 var userControl = ((ResourceCategories)this.Page).FindControl("ctlPopUp") as UserControl; still the value I get is null

Comment: Does `var userControl=ctlPopUp` work? As I explained above, you need to better explain your question so that it's clear what code goes with which file.

Comment: OKie Mason... I will try to explain. I have to complete it asap.
The main ASPX page ResourceCategories.aspx has two user controls ctlCategories(which is ResourceCenter.ascx usercontrol) and ctlPopUp(DownLoadList.ascx usercontrol)
What I need is ResourceCenter.ascx has a button control btnArrow. On click of btnArrow_Click I like to access ctlPopUp. Hope its clear

Comment: check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With this code you don't need to use `FindControl`, since you have only a single `categoryPopup` directly on your page, declared using `runat="server"`:

`<downloadPopUp:categoryPopup id="ctlPopUp" runat="server"></downloadPopUp:categoryPopup>`

Therefore in your code you can use `ctlPopup` directly to access the control.

Comment: That's true. ctlpopup works in the main page(ResourceCategories.aspx.cs). The problem is that like to access ctlpopup in both ResourceCategories.aspx.cs and ResourceCenter.ascx.cs page. IF I register ctlpopup in both ResourceCategories.aspx and ResourceCenter.ascx(which is already registered in ResourceCategories.aspx)  page it works. Not sure whether its the right way to do.

Comment: For that problem, in ResourceCenter.ascx you need to use `Page.FindControl("ctlPopUp")`, not `FindControl("ctlPopUp")`. Unqualified, `FindControl` searches the current control, which in your example is ResourceCenter.ascx, hence it's not finding the popup because it's in a different control (the page).